# Return different outputs for a input when both are different methods

Tags: junit, mockito, powermock

I have class

```
class CommandRunner {
  String output;

  public int run(String command) {
    //runs command and sets output         
    return errCode;
  }

  public String getOutput() {
    return output;
  }
}
```

Above CommandRunner is being in my class under test as

```
CommandRunner runner;
runner.run("some command");
out = runner.getOutput();
//operates on out

runner.run("some command");
out = runner.getOutput();
//operates on out

runner.run("some command");
out = runner.getOutput();
//operates on out
```

How can I mock CommandRunner to return different outputs based on input to run() method ? I using Power Mock with Mockito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a Mockito `Answer`, which is a chunk of code that is run when a method on a mock is called.  You could write an `Answer` that checks the argument passed to the method, and returns something different in each case.  Check out http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html for how to do this.